# When creating a Resharper template, can you get a macro parameter to select from a list of enum values?

Tags: resharper, resharper-8.0

I am creating a ReSharper template and need to add a macro that sets a value which can only be selected from an enum.  Is it possible to do this in ReSharper?  I have a command named $AUTHOR$ and I need it to resolve to EnumAuthors.??  Where ?? is where I pick teh enum value I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Execute smart completion" or "Execute basic completion" macros to provide code completion for the values of an enum. For example:

```
public void Foo()
{
  var author = EnumAuthors.$VALUE$;
}
```

when you come to expand `$VALUE$`, code completion will display just the values of `EnumAuthors`.